# Alter each column named 'xxx'

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a PostgreSQL stored procedure that must set default value 'now()' to each columns named 'CreationDate' in every tables.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_creation_date() RETURNS
void AS $$
DECLARE
     t pg_tables%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
     FOR t IN SELECT "tablename" FROM pg_tables WHERE "schemaname" = 'public'  LOOP
     IF EXISTS (select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = t."tablename"
    and column_name = 'CreationDate') THEN
    EXECUTE FORMAT('ALTER TABLE %I ALTER COLUMN "CreationDate" SET DEFAULT now()', t."tablename");
    END IF;
     END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But no columns are affected. What's wrong?

Comment: looks like your execute string is not created correctly. - you should be appending the value of tablename not the fixed string.

Comment: Yes, i have edited my function, but it still doesn't work. I'm quite sure that it's a syntax error in that "tablename", but i can't find it

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it's trying to alter `t."tablename"` every time. Try the following instead:

```
EXECUTE FORMAT('ALTER TABLE %I ALTER COLUMN "CreationDate" SET DEFAULT now()', t."tablename");
```

I don't have a PostgreSQL server available to test, so please let me know if the syntax isn't quite right.

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work. Your suggestion is correct, i have edited my question with yours and other corrections. After execute it, no errors but still no rows affected

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved. The error was in pg_tables%ROWTYPE: using debugger i realized that the field 'tablename' doesn't exist, so i declared 't' as text.
I created a function with parameters, where you have to pass schema name and column name. I ll post it here for anyone who ll need it

```
    DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS set_creation_date(character varying, character varying);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_creation_date(_schema_name character varying, _column_date character varying)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
     t TEXT;
BEGIN
     FOR t IN SELECT "tablename" FROM pg_tables WHERE "schemaname" = _schema_name  LOOP
     IF EXISTS (select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = t and column_name = _column_date) THEN
    EXECUTE FORMAT('ALTER TABLE %I ALTER COLUMN %I SET DEFAULT now()', t, _column_date);
    END IF;
     END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```